# Disabling beamer animations easily

Tags: animations, beamer

I'm writing a presentation for a conference with beamer. I'm using `\pause` commands in order to show the contents one piece at a time, but it's really annoying having to scroll through so much pages while I'm writing slides.
After a little bit (read: lot of) googling, I found about the `handout` documentclass option, that seems to do just what I was looking for.

My question is: since I would like to have pauses in the presentation before every list item and before every block in general, is there a way to tell beamer to automatically do this, please? With my current solution it's easy to enable/disable slides animations, but it's quite a nuisance having to manually add `\pause` everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess there are at least three alternatives for your problem, the four slides in the following example all do the same:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first one
        \pause
    \item second one
        \pause
    \item third one
        \pause
    \item fourth one
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> first one
    \item<2-> second one
    \item<3-> third one
    \item<4-> fourth one
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> first one
    \item<+-> second one
    \item<+-> third one
    \item<+-> fourth one
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item first one
    \item second one
    \item third one
    \item fourth one
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

- the first one is you solution
- the second one tells at which slides to appear, `<3->` meaning all starting from the third one
- the third one is used to increase the counter `beamerpause` (=1 at beginning of frame) by one at each encounter
- the fourth one (probably the one you would go for) sets the "increase beamerpause" as a default behaviour for all list items

---

**Edit 1:** You can also set the behaviour from the fourth example as general. All frames following `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` will set pauses for every `actionenv` environment and every `\item`. To be in effect globally, you need to set this outside of a frame, e.g. as the first line after `\begin{document}`, before the first frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` is exactly what I was looking for.